# Max function not giving right answer

Tags: prolog, max

In Prolog, I made a `Max` function, however, I am trying to compare the number it returns to others, and can tell that it isn't giving me the right number. My list will be `[2,2,1,2]` so my `max` should be 2, but when I compare the max found with 2, it fails.

My code looks like this:

```
maximumElement([X], X).
maximumElement([H|T], MaxFound):-
    maximumElement(T, MaxOfTail),
    MaxFound = max(MaxOfTail, H).
```

My problem could also be where I am comparing the numbers, but right now I have changed it so that that predicate looks like this when called:

```
maximumElement(List, MaxFound),
checkIfTwo(MaxFound, MaxFound).
```

And this in it's predicate:

```
checkIfTwo(2,2).
```

Since I am comparing it like that, it seems weird that I would get false, because I am comparing the same numbers, so I think it has to be a problem with my compare or finding the max.

Comment: In Prolog `=` is not an expression assignment. It's a term unification operator. It's not the same thing. Arithmetic functions, need an arithmetic operator, or `is/2`.

Comment: @lurker I have tried using `is/2` where I have `MaxFound = max(MaxOfTail, H)` and it still outputs the wrong answer, so I don't think that is the problem.

Comment: You should write `MaxFound is max(MaxOfTail, H)` instead

Comment: All I did was change your `MaxFound = max(MaxOfTail, H)` to `MaxFound is max(MaxOfTail, H)` and then `maximumElement/2` yielded the correct results. I also tried, `maximumElement([2, 2, 1, 2], M), checkIfTwo(M, M).` and it also succeeded with `M = 2`.Try again.

Answer (score 0):

As said by everyone in the comments it is enough to say

```
maximumElement([X], X).
maximumElement([H|T], MaxFound):-
    maximumElement(T, MaxOfTail),
    MaxFound is max(MaxOfTail, H).
```

but I write answer anyway because you have issues, it is not just any element, it must be number or arithmetic expression because you use `is max()`, so name is not too great, and also you get choicepoint even though there is no choices left. Look:

```
?- maximumElement([1+2,2], Max).
Max = 3 ;
false.
```

So maybe you can instead write:

```
max_arith_expr([X|Xs], Max) :-
    max_arith_expr(Xs, X, Max).

max_arith_expr([], X, X).
max_arith_expr([X|Xs], X0, Max) :-
    max_arith_expr(Xs, X, Max0),
    Max is max(X0, Max0).
```

But why really is it non-tail-recursive? Maybe necessary, or maybe not? Because if you already have three arguments you can just accumulate maximum

```
max_arith_expr([], Max, Max).
max_arith_expr([X|Xs], Max0, Max) :-
    Max1 is max(X, Max0),
    max_arith_expr(Xs, Max1, Max).
```

But I am afraid this now looks exactly like what you alrady had [here in the library](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/caea389b1d611493d5800e6ad6e9247104695e42/library/lists.pl#L548-L561) so I don't know if this is somehow good or bad or both?